# How to run an exe from a button click

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, exe

So as the title says I want to be able to run an .exe that is in the same directory as the  .exe that you click the button in to launch the program. This is an example of the code I am using to launch it

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Application.StartupPath\\f0rcast.exe");
```

any answers are appreciated thanks

Comment: found out what I was doing wrong
its this instead

                 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iReb.exe");
and it ran

Comment: In that case can you either delete your question or answer it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out what I was doing wrong
its this instead that worked for me

```
             System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iReb.exe");
```